# Is it possible to convert a string to its ExpressionType counterpart?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a string variable that will be set to something like `Add` or `Subtract` and was wondering if it would be possible to convert it to the `System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionType` of `Add` or `Subtract` so that I can then use it in my `Expression.MakeBinary()`.

Right now I have something that looks similar to this:

```
var operands = "Subtract"
Expression.MakeBinary(operands, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(50),System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Constant(20));
```

I realize that this may not be the best code, I am really just trying to limit my room for error right now and see if it is possible to convert a string to it's ExpressionType.

`Note:` It has crossed my mind that it would be possible to do this with a switch, but my end result is to try and make calculations as dynamic as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `ExpressionType` is just an `enum`. Here is how you can parse your string into an `ExpressionType`:

```
ExpressionType t = (ExpressionType)Enum.Parse(typeof(ExpressionType), "Subtract");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `Enum.Parse` (or TryParse, depending on which is appropriate in context) to parse a string representing a value in an enumeration into an appropriate instance of that enumeration.